# JAXP SAX-парсер, Как остановить парсинг после нахождения определённого поля?

Tags: java, xmlparser, sax

JAXP SAX-парсер, Как остановить парсинг после нахождения определённого поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выкинуть исключение

```
try {
    ...
    xmlReader.parse();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    if (e.Cause instanceof BreakParsingException) {
        // ваше исключение
        ....
    }
}
```

Выкидывать можно в любом месте в обработчике(эксепшн наследуйте от  SAXParseException):

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI,
                     String localName,
                     String qName,
                     Attributes atts)
              throws SAXException {
    // ...
    throw new SAXException(new BreakParsingException());
}
```